# Android, dealing with closing cursors

Tags: java, android

I have made a rookie mistake, I wrote my entire app without closing any cursors. This works, until the app is closed and reopened.

Now, however, I am going through and closing my cursors like so:

```
public boolean contains (int pk)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try
    {
        cursor = //cursor assigned;

       if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                if (cursor.getInt(/*PK COLUMN*/) == pk)
                    return true;
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cursor!= null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is a different solution but it declares a pointless temp variable and closes the cursor in different areas.

```
public boolean contains (int pk)
{
    Cursor cursor = //value;

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            int val = cursor.getInt(/*PK COLUMN*/);
            if(pk == val)
            {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with using try-finally to clean up after a return statement?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No. That first example is fine, and I believe the recommended way to do it.

Comment: @ShadowGod, fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first solution, you are returning true inside do without closing cursor.
But it's good practice to close in finally.